# Как отключить перенос текста для Label?

Tags: ios, swift, label

У меня выводится массив в label. Но почему то текст не обрезается троеточием, а переносится на другую строку. Как это можно исправить?

[image: jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите количество строк равное 1:

Interface builder

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или в коде:

```
someLabel.numberOfLines = 1
```

---

Также можете установить как будет обрезаться текст, задав `Line Break` в Interface Builder или `.lineBreakMode` в коде.

Comment: отличное решение, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Выставил height фиксированный. Всем спасибо

Comment: И как Вы определите необходимое значение для высоты? Если Вы, например, шрифт поменяете, опять придётся код поправлять?